# Blazor Server Side - sharing values from Parent (Mainlayout) to Child Component (Pages)

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Good Day everyone

On my project, I have created a simple cookie authentication, now on my MainLayout.razor, and created a separate code file (MainLayout.razor.cs), now on the code file, I put a code that gets the authenticated user.

```
            var AuthState = await authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var GetUser = AuthState.User;
            string strUser = AuthState.User.Claims.First().Value.ToString();
            EmpDetails GetEmpDetails = myServices.GetUserDetails(strUser)
```

Now, I want the GetEmpDetails to share it with the child components, my current setup is, I have to call this code again on each page, Is there a way to share this from Parent to Child components?

Thanks and regards

Comment: its batter to create a service that hold that kind of information and register it with ServiceProvider (DI Container) as singleton. then it will be available in application any time you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class like

```
public class DataService
{
    public Dictionary<string, EmpDetails> EmpDetails { get; set; }
}
```

register service in Program.cs, it may be Startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataService>();
```

now in MainLayout

```
[Inject]
private DataService DataService { get; set; }
        
if (DataService.EmpDetails.ContainsKey(EmpLoginId))
    DataService.EmpDetails.Remove(EmpLoginId);
DataService.EmpDetails.Add(EmpLoginId, EmpDetails);
```

Now in any blazor component

```
[Inject]
private DataService DataService { get; set; }
```

and you can get user like

```
var empDetails = DataService.EmpDetails[EmpLoginId];
```

Comment: You want to make the authenticated user a singleton?

Comment: Hi Muhammad thanks for this, this works for me, I have a question regarding singleton, does the variable pass on singleton only exist on the user's browser who is currently logged in? or does this share to all users who are also logged in at the same time? hehe sorry, I don't want to cause a problem when the user see a different name on their page.

Comment: @CaiusJard for authentication I used cookies, what I want to attempt is to get the logged-on user details that are called on the Mainlayout and share them to the child components (pages), my current setup is I still calling the employee details on each page, which for me is too repetitive when you can call it on the MainLayout page.

Comment: @hydeinthesky29 my answer do exactly what you have asked for, by the way which type of project is this?, Blazor, ASP.NET Web Api, ASP.NET MVC because there might be different solution for each of those

Comment: First tell me the type of project you are using, Is it Blazor Server, Blazor Web Assembly or ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API

Comment: I have edited the answer to meet your requirement

Comment: Hi @MuhammadWaqasAziz sorry for the late response, I'm using Blazor Server Side, which is on the title and on the tags of this post (sorry), thanks for this, I will try your solution, thanks again.